# What is the point of living a life if we're all going to eventually die?

Tags: motivation, philosophy-of-mind, depression, fear

So I've had this question over the past week since New Years. I am currently 21 years old and yea, time flies so fast. New years just feels like one year closer to death. Can you believe it? The internet was founded around the years when I was born. Can you believe where we are today? Can you believe that it's 70% through the decade already? Yet 7 years ago, I was barely in high school and iPads were invented?

So at the start of New Years, I've started to get this feeling "what is the point of living life if eventually we'll all die"? And furthermore, I got another question. If we die, doesn't everything come to an end? Don't you lose memory of absolutely everything you've done in life? So in other words, what's the point of doing things in life if we're all going to eventually die and never even remember what we've done? Maybe other people might but would you personally have remembered this upon your death? I'm talking in a non-religious point of view. From a scientific logical point of view, everything you've done in life comes to an end and you cannot even backtrack anything to trace your memories or whatnot. I don't believe that scientifically there is a such thing as "afterlife" or whatnot.

So really, I got extremely depressed over the past few days thinking about this question. I mean you can be the richest person in the world right now but in probably ~80 years, you'll completely forget about that. Or otherwise you can live in total misery and poverty but you'll forget about it maybe 50 years later.

So this question has struck my head really hard. I felt like I didn't want to do anything. What is the actual point of life if we're all going to die no matter what we have accomplished?

Comment: I am not being negative about you or the question, but I think that if you are suffering depression and this subject is the cause, then you need to find a good counsellor to discuss this with.  Using forums is not the best place to do this as it can do more harm than good

Comment: This only makes sense when you presume the purpose in life is to live forever; it is not. ;p

Comment: @StevenJeuris, I would argue the assumption is that the purpose of life is to be aware of and/or have memory for one's accomplishments/ experiences.  Certainly I would guess that one has neither following death, but that is an extra assumption.  It's also a more cognitive way of considering the question; that is, is memory necessary to make life meaningful?

Comment: This question is very common and is often the starting point of spiritual inquiry. If you don't ask it, you never have a life, so I am glad to welcome you to being 'awake' to reality for the first time. Albert Camus famously said: "*The only real philosophical question is whether or not to commit suicide.*"

Comment: Have you ever enjoyed a vdo game or sports or movies or sex or food. There must be something, for example sake let’s say video game, may be ‘Mario’, now what’s the point in that?, it just fictional but it just amuses you, your brain enjoys solving puzzles/challenges etc in it. 

I may say live life for pleasure, that’s one school of thought, formally known as Hedonism. Like that some  find point of life in other stuff like religion, spirituality, mix of stuff.... With or without point, it is worth living cuz you gonna die one day anyway.

Comment: Also apart from philosophy, we deal with a lot of biology, loss of interest, suicidal thoughts can also be results of chemical imbalance in mind, one must seek medical help before giving into any compulsion of own brain.